# Unable to deploy "ReadOnly" permission on externalSharingModel

Tags: managed-package, sharing

I am facing a build error that the object xml I modified to have the externalSharingModel as ReadOnly does not work. I just gave below this xml in the object xml file.

```
<externalSharingModel>ReadOnly</externalSharingModel>
```

I am not sure if this is the right value for this node or not. Basically I was trying to change the object xml from ReadWrite to ReadOnly.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357426/edit) your question to include the *exact* error text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Read`.

From *Metadata API Developer Guide*

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm#meta_type_SharingModel

> ...valid values are:
>
> - `Private`
> - `Read`
> - `ReadWrite`
> - `ReadWriteTransfer`
> - `FullAccess`
> - `ControlledByParent`
> - `ControlledByCampaign`
> - `ControlledByLeadOrContact`

Comment: Thanks @moonpie will try that.